# Randomly generate a list of arbitrary length from a finite set

Tags: random

I have a finite set of elements (5 to be exact). Suppose the first element has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of being selected, while each of the others has probability $\frac{1}{8}$ of being selected. How can I generate a string of length $n$ from this set corresponding to these associated probabilities? The length of the string doesn't really matter. I just want it somewhere between 10 and 20 characters long.

Comment: RandomChoice...

Comment: To expand on @ciao's comment, would `StringJoin@RandomChoice[{1/2, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8} -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, 20]` work for you?